# data coming from custom fetch hook and local state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have a local setter to update data I'm extracting from custom fetch hook:

```
  function ContactList(props) {
  const contacts =useFetch(fetchUrl, []);**//contain data**
  const [data,setData] = useState(contacts);**//remains empty**

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <ul className="collection">
        <ContactItem contacts={contacts} setContacts={setData} />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

fetchHook looks like this:

```
export const useFetch = (url, initialValue) => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState(initialValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(url);
            setResult(result.data.contact);
        };
        fetchData();
        
    }, []);
   
return result
}
```

so I need the contactList to have a setter which I currently don't manage to achieve because state remain an empty array.

Comment: Thats cool, was there a question here? are you experiencing any issues? What does your custom `useFetch` look like? we have no context so please explain in more detail whats going on so we can help you get to the desired result.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks. I added more details, if you see what is wrong please share some insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const contacts =useFetch(fetchUrl, []);
```

useFetch is asynchronous and makes the call and gives the result after the componentMounts, since I'm assuming you put that in a useEffect with empty dependency in your hook. 
So, the data won't be available on the first render, making it initialize to empty.

**EDIT:**
To understand better, follow the `console.log` in the following example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-ives-xt5k0

You'll see that it is empty first and then it gets the value.

Now, the same is the case in your code. On the first render it's empty and that is when you set the state of result. Instead, you can just use the value of `contacts` in your case.

**EDIT 2:**
After seeing what you need, all you have to do is to also return the `setResult` from the hook:

```
export const useFetch = (url, initialValue) => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState(initialValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(url);
            setResult(result.data.contact);
        };
        fetchData();

    }, []);

return {result, setResult}
}
```

```
function ContactList(props) {
  const {result, setResult} =useFetch(fetchUrl, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <ul className="collection">
        <ContactItem contacts={result} setContacts={setResult} />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. could you elaborate ? with some code example ?

Comment: Added an example, check it out and let me know.

Comment: yeah but the problem is that I need a setter for later code , thus the need for useState

Comment: You need to add more code to understand what you are trying to do. Can you add the ContactItem component?

Comment: Where are you using data?

Comment: contactsItem is a component being called by two other: contactList and SearchBar so it receive contacts as props from these two components, for example in the searchbar the contacts are being manipulated (delete or update functions for ex) ,  that is why a setter is also sent as props in order to manage updates so I need a similar mechanisme with contactList so I can call contactItem with a setter as a props

Comment: function ContactItem({ contacts, setContacts }) {
  async function handleDelete(id) {
    try {
      await axios(deleteUrl + id);
      let results = contacts.filter(item => item._id !== id);
      setContacts(results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  return contacts.map(contact => ( stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199218/discussion-between-paruchuri-p-and-random-dreamer).

Comment: you are right, it solved the problem . Thanks a lot.